# Use ngAnimate on template in directive

Tags: angularjs

I have this function,

```
app.directive('movieDetails', MovieDetailsDirectiveFn)
   .controller('MovieRowCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', MovieRowCtrlFn]);

function MovieDetailsDirectiveFn() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      movie: '='
    },
    templateUrl: '/tpl.html',
    // template: '<div class="movie" style="background-image:url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280{{movie.backdrop}})">{{movie.title}}</div>'
  }
}

function MovieRowCtrlFn($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.selectedMovie;
  $scope.rowActive = false;


  $scope.$on('movieRowActivated', ($event, dataObject) => {
    if ($scope.$id != dataObject.targetScopeId) {
      $scope.rowActive = false;
    }
  });


  $scope.updateSelectedMovie = function updateVisibleMovieIndexFn(movie) {
    $scope.selectedMovie = movie;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('movieRowActivated', {targetScopeId: $scope.$id});
    $scope.rowActive = true;
    console.log ('hello')
  }
}
```

And this html,

```
<div class="content" ng-repeat="movie in movieGroup" ng-init='$movieIndex = $index'>
  <a href='' ng-click='updateSelectedMovie(movie)'>{{ movie.title }}</a>
</div>

<div ng-if='rowActive'>
  <movie-details movie='selectedMovie'></movie-details>
</div>
```

When a user clicks on a button the `updateSelectedMovie` function triggers and the directive element `movie-details` is updated with new information.

Check the plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/Ea1OtRUc1wvC4UNw1sNi?p=preview

What I want to do is animate a fadeOut/fadeIn transition when the `movie-details` directive element changes content. I've used ngAnimate on ui-router elements, since they get the ng-enter ng-animate classes etc. but that doesn't work with a directive.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problemn. I "fixed" this by putting a ui-view inside the template that's being loaded by the directive. And fixed a state with it. So now the directive creates a template and goes to another state. The state then places the template inside the freshly created ui-view (from the directive) and now I can animate that element.